# JQuery active menu Issue while using filters

Tags: jquery, menu, highlight

I am using this jQuery code to highlight the active menus:

```
$(function(){
   var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
   if ( path )
     $('#topnav a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'active');
 });
```

Its working fine. The problem is at one of the Menu Pages , i am using a alphabetic filter. So when i click on any of the alphabets to filter the users , the highlight goes off.

How do i resolve this problem?

Comment: Why not let the server serve you with the `active` class instead of having to use JQuery?

Comment: can you provide demo code of your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function extractPageName(hrefString) {
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return (arr.length < 2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length - 2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length - 1].toLowerCase();
}

function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage) {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV") {
                arr[i].className = "selected";
                arr[i].parentNode.className = "selected";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage() {
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;

    if (document.getElementById("navigation") != null)
        setActiveMenu(document.getElementById("navigation").getElementsByTagName("a"), extractPageName(hrefString));
}
```

and add this function at end of the html code (after last div)

setPage()